# VPN user restricted login to workstations cannot login to VPN server

Tags: active-directory, vpn, sonicwall

We have a vendor that requires Domain Admin access on the servers where their software is deployed. (Obviously we want to restrict them to only being able to login to the servers where their software is deployed.) In AD, we have used the "Log On To..." to restrict that user to those particular servers.

However, our VPN (Sonicwall NSA 2400) cannot authenticate the user when restricted servers are set. It returns: "80090308: LdapErr: DSID-0C0903A9, comment: AcceptSecurityContext error, data 531, v1db1". According to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/15024909), the error is that the Sonicwall is not a permitted workstation. I have added the IP of the Sonicwall to the allowed workstations, but it has not removed the error. When I change the logon restriction to all workstations, the user is allowed to login to the VPN and the Sonicwall says login successful.

Is there a way I can get the Sonicwall to authenticate the user while still keeping the restricted login? I am open to alternatives to our method.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the reason it can't authenticate is because that user can't authenticate against the DC as it's not one of the servers you've allowed access to.

If you allow the connection across the board as you've suggested and then limit the access for that user to only allow remote access to specific servers on the individual servers in question then he should be able to auth against the DC but not log into it.

Hope that made sense.

Comment: I have added the user to allow login to the Domain controller that authenticates the VPN connections. This is allowing access, but would like to limit the user to not even be able to remote to the domain controller.

Comment: If you go onto the domain controller and navigate to

Control Panel > System and Security> System.

Click remote settings, at the bottom go to select users and make sure he's not in that list, and is not a member of an AD group that is in that list.

Answer (score 0):

Does the vendor actually require Domain Admin access, or would local Administrator rights on the servers they manage being enough?
If they actually require Domain Admin access, restricting them to login to one or more server is fairly pointless: they would still be able to make domain-wide changes using any LDAP tool (including the built-in RSAT tools available on any Windows server). They could even remove those restrictions by themselves.
If they instead only need administrative rights on some servers, just add them to the local Administrators group on those machines and have them be standard domain users elsewhere.